# Select item without a particular child of X

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

For the following xml

```
<Root>
  <A><B>....</B></A>
  <A><B>....</B><X>...</X></A>
```

I'm using the following xquery in SQL Server 2008R2. How to get the elements of `A` without child `X`?

```
select @xml.query('<r>...
{ for $a in //A return 
   <a>... {... $a[????] ...} .... (: use $a which doesn''t have child X only :)
     { for $x in $a/X return <x>... $x ...</x> } (: otherwise use //a/x :)
   </a>
}</r>')
```

**Update:**
Testable example:

```
declare @xml xml = '
<Root>
  <A><B>123</B><C>***</C></A>
  <A><B>456</B><C>***</C><X>abc</X></A>
</Root>'

select @xml.query('<r>
{ for $a in //A return 
   <a>{ $a/B/text() }  (: use $a which doesn''t have child X only :)
     { for $x in $a/X return $x/text() } (: otherwise use //a/x :)
   </a>
}</r>')
```

expected `<r><a>123</a><a>abc</a></r>` instead of `<r><a>123</a><a>456abc</a></r>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get node without children in xQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026038/how-to-get-node-without-children-in-xquery)

Comment: @dirkk They are totally different questions.

Comment: well, looking again I agree it is not the most appropriate one, SO search is unfortunately not the best. But the generic question (How to return an XML node without some children) has been asked many times before here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159100/xquery-that-selects-node-but-omits-returning-child-nodes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547381/how-to-select-with-omitting-a-specific-child-using-xpath

Comment: @dirkk These two questions are still very different.

Comment: No, they are not. Maybe it is because I come from an XQuery background, but the principle is exactly the same to me.

Comment: The purpose is different. My question is not not removing a child element but do something if a particular child element doesn't exist. I don't see how they are principle the same.

Comment: I don't think the question is duplicated with these questions too.

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry, but this wasn't clear for me from the question. As you ask _"How to get the elements of A without child X?"_ I expected you to want exactly this as a result. Rewording this to what you said in your last comment would have helped me a lot. However, I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml = '
<Root>
  <A><B>123</B></A>
  <A><B>456</B><X>abc</X></A>
</Root>'

select @xml.query('
<r>{
    for $a in //A
    return <a>{
        if (count($a/X) = 0)
        then $a/*/text()
        else $a/X/text()
    }</a>
}</r>
')
```

Comment: It also removed the first `<B>..</B` text when testing `declare @xml xml = '
<Root>
  <A><B>123</B></A>
  <A><B>456</B><X>abc</X></A>
</Root>'
select @xml.query('<r>
{ for $a in //A return 
   <a>{ for $c in $a/*
     where local-name($c) != "X"
  return $c/B/text() }  (: use $a which doesn''t have child X only :)
     { for $x in $a/X return $x/text() } (: otherwise use //a/x :)
   </a>
}</r>')`. Very strange.

Comment: Thanks. The updated returns `<r><a>123</a><a>456</a></r>` instead of expected `<r><a>123</a><a>abc</a></r>`. BTW, the `<A>` may have other children and they shouldn't be in the output.

Comment: Generally `string()` and `node-name()` should be used instead of `text()` or `local-name()`. There are exceptions, but those are safer.

Comment: The new answer doesn't use any of those.

Comment: I still see `text()` in your answer. This will return all text node children, which may not be what you want, depending on the content of the parent node. If you simply want the string value of an element, then use `string()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for $a in //A return 
element { node-name($a) } {
  $a/*[local-name(.) != 'X']
}
```

Reconstructing the element name dynamically isn't necessary, but assuming this is a simplified example, it might come in handy if you are iterating over non-identical element names.

Comment: How to select child `B` of `$a/* except $a/X`?

Comment: BTW, Sql server 2008 xquery doesn't support `except`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed `node-name` to `local-name` since SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `node-name`. But I still got error `XQuery [query()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xs:string' to 'xs:QName'`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 This is because `node-name()` returns an 'xs:QName' type, not `xs:string`. If you have to use `local-name()`, then you have to compare it to a string. See updated answer.